sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: non-commutative expressions are not supported
I hit the following error using sympy.groebner: "sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: non-commutative expressions are not supported".
In the real case, I have a very diffcult expression which is not easy to reduce. The beginning of the polynom p to reduce is

And I get (where compute_vtmv_product compute a polynomial p that should be reduced using Groebner basis)

I tried to reduce the problem (the same way the variables are created / used in the real example) but the problem seems to disappear

In the real case, variables are mixed, so I tried adding a/b/c variables mixed with x/y/z variables but I get

Does somebody have any clue on the cause of these problems?
UPDATE
p is a polynomial which real coefs (not integer nor rational).
Any clue on how to fix / find or transform this problem to something what could work would be great!

Please add code, not pictures, so people will be able to easily reproduce your problem. sympy 1.5.1 is from 5 years ago - have you tried this on recent version of sympy?

Old version for reason I didn't choose. I realized this before reading this answer, I upgraded to 1.13.3 and reproduced the CoercionFailed error

You are using an older version of SymPy but with the latest version 1.13.1 you would see a different error here:
CoercionFailed: expected an integer, got a

The reason is that the Groebner reduce method expects that the expression to be reduced should be a polynomial with the same generators and domain as is used for the Groebner basis. There are two ways to do this:

Add the symbols a, b and c as variables to the basis.
Compute a basis over a domain that includes the symbols a, b and c

In [21]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [22]: a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')

In [23]: groebner([x, y, z])
Out[23]: GroebnerBasis([x, y, z], x, y, z, domain=ℤ, order=lex)

In [24]: groebner([x, y, z], [x, y, z, a, b, c])
Out[24]: GroebnerBasis([x, y, z], x, y, z, a, b, c, domain=ℤ, order=lex)

In [25]: groebner([x, y, z], domain=QQ[a, b, c])
Out[25]: GroebnerBasis([x, y, z], x, y, z, domain=ℚ[a, b, c], order=lex)

In [26]: G = groebner([x, y, z], domain=QQ[a, b, c])

In [27]: p = a*x + b*y + c*z

In [28]: G.reduce(p)
Out[28]: ([a, b, c], 0)


Thanks for this answer. Still need to look at the doc to get what is the second arg of groebner and what domains are. In real case, the coefs of the poly are real, and, I have no idea what a, b, c may be (I just have the p polynomial shown in the very first image). I overviewed the doc this morning and felt like groebner only supports integer or rational coefs which is not my case: I guess this may explain why I hit, in the real case, a "non-commutative" error (but not a CoercionFailed error thrown by toy - not real - examples)

The coefficients can be in any domain but by default ZZ or QQ are chosen if the coefficients of the input polynomials are integer or rational. I showed how to specify a polynomial ring domain instead. The domain needs to contain the coefficients of the polynomial you are trying to reduce.
